# Multiple file rename in bash.

Tags: bash, file, for-loop, renaming

Just starting out with Bash, and I am trying to write something to easily rename multiple files. The difficulty is that it's not just a simple append or changing of extension.

The files I am trying to name are from this format

```
IIS-1af24fa93f090177fe770e1213caf3a3-443.hex
```

To this format

```
1af24fa93f090177fe770e1213caf3a3
```

I have got something like this so far, but it returns **errors**

```
for f in ./* ; do mv "$f" "$(ls /root/download_logs/ | cut -d \- -f2)" ; done
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: `returns errors`? Elaborate.

Comment: Also, parsing `ls` output should be [avoided](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thanks for that. Didn't realise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
for f in IIS-*.hex; do
  newname=${f%-*}
  newname=${newname#*-}
  mv "$f" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: This works great! The -raw is still on the end of the filename, but I'm hoping I can figure out how to get rid of that bit based on the method you've showed me.

Comment: What `-raw`? There is no `-raw` in your question.

Comment: My bad, I just realised that. I meant to copy in two examples, but I only copied in one.

It's fine now though, as I have the solution thanks to you. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the problem rename files now, what is the `${%0*}` called @AnsgarWiechers? so that I can do research and understand your script.